# what is ${array[three]}

Tags: shell, ksh

I am learning shell(ksh) scripting. I wanted to know what does `${array[three]}` mean in this context.

```
array[1]="one"
array[2]="two"
array[3]="three"
three=3

print ${array[1]}
print ${array[2]}
print ${array[3]}
print ${array[three]}
```

The Output:

```
one
two
three
three
```

I understand that we just declare a simple array that holds `{one,two,three}` as it's values. But i dont understand why `print ${array[three]}` outputs `three`. My main double is isnt it should be `print ${array[$three]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also write:

```
print ${array[$three]}
```

and it will produce the same answer (`three`).  It appears that within the scope of the `${...}`, the Korn shell automatically assumes that any word that could be a variable name is and implicitly applies the `$` to it.

Comment: ok thanks @JonathanLeffler :) So if i understood properly now: `print ${array[three]}` IS same as `print ${array[$three]}` BUT `print ${array['three']}` IS different? Could you explain if there is any difference now(if there is) between `print ${array[three]}` And `print ${array['three']}`

Comment: Urgh - you want me to read the manual now?  Darn it - that's hard work; can't you do it for me?  :-D

Comment: I didn't do any explicit array creation operations; I just ran the code you gave in the question on the MacOS X (10.7.2) version of ksh. And when I try: `$ array['three']=kitchen; print ${array['three']}`, I get "kitchen", as you'd expect, ... BUT ... when I try `print ${array[three]}` I also get "kitchen" and when I try `print ${array[$three]}` I still get "kitchen". So, my explanation is a bit too facile; quoted strings get treated as if they were variable identifiers (minus the quotes) too. I'm not sure whether `ksh` has associative arrays (indexed by strings) or not. That's RTFM territory.